# What type does open("file", "r") return

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to open a file, read it, then split it.

However, I have no idea how to change the file into a string, and when I run this small chunk, it gives an `AttributeError`.

Is there a way to turn this file into a string?

```
into = open("file.in", "r")
into = into.split()
```

Comment: Have you read the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) on this yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`open()` returns an object of type `file`;

```
>>> type(open('file'))
<type 'file'>
```

You can read the data from the file and split it like this:

```
with open('file') as f:
    into = f.read().split()
```

This will produce a list containing all of the words in the file because `split()` splits by whitespace. If you wanted a list of lines, use `readlines()` instead:

```
with open('file') as f:
    into = f.readlines()
```

Note that the more common usage is to open the file and *iterate* line-by-line over its contents using a `for` loop:

```
with open('file') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line.split()    # for example
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns a file object, which you can read from with `into.read()`. This returns a string containing the file's contents that you can then split: `into.read().split()`. You may also iterate over the lines of a file with `for line in into:`.